# Populate TableView from Database (iOS6 SQLite3)

Tags: ios6, sqlite, tableview

I am currently populating a TableView's cells with static data.

For ex.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
   [super viewDidLoad]; 
   _carNamesArray = @[@"Porsche", @"Ferrari", @"Fiat"]; 
}
```

Can someone point me at an example that would show me how to load the data from a SQLite database instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial- ['How To Develop an iPhone or iPad App using SQLite Data and an UITableView | iOS |'](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-How-To-Display-SQLite-Data-in-a-UITableView).
Hope it'll help you.

Comment: This is a dumb realization with complete  data pump from sqlite to the ram. What if database contains one billion records (sort of GEO positions for example) ?